# Is this a bug in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm facing a problem in SQL Server which I think is a bug - but I'm not sure.

My users have entered a negative number with a space between sign and number. So in my code when I check that the value is numeric, its result is *true* but when I try to convert it to float it has an error...

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC('- 49.5')
```

Result : 1

```
SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT, '- 49.5')
```

> Error converting data type varchar to float.

Answer (score 4):

From [BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql):

> **ISNUMERIC returns 1 for some characters that are not numbers, such as
>   plus (+), minus (-), and valid currency symbols such as the dollar
>   sign ($).** For a complete list of currency symbols, see money and
>   smallmoney (Transact-SQL).

Better to use `TRY_CAST/CONVERT/PARSE` (SQL Server 2012+):

```
SELECT TRY_CAST('- 49.5' AS FLOAT);
```

If your number represents price/size/... I strongly suggest to use `DECIMAL/NUMERIC` over `FLOAT`.

**EDIT:**

> I can not use TRY_CAST. because ISNUMERIC changes the flow of my codes.

Yes you can:

```
IF TRY_CAST(@val AS FLOAT) IS NULL
     -- @val is not a number
ELSE
     -- @val is number
```

Comment: I can not use TRY_CAST. because ISNUMERIC changes the flow of my codes. I have two types of the answers including number and word and I check a range for numbers and something else for words.

Comment: Rather than the notoriously impractical `isnumeric` you can also use something like `like '%^[a-Z]%'` to check for numeric. (Code from memory, maybe it's not copy-paste ready)

Comment: @HoneyBadger So ISNUMERC is not the thing that its name say to us!

Comment: @SiamakFerdos It is and it isn't. It tells us if a string can be converted to any numeric datatype, which can be counterintuitive

Comment: Of course, there is nothing stopping you (in theory at least) to write your own function. Or find one online, there's no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @SiamakFerdos . . . `try_cast()`/`try_convert()` is the right solution.  I have no idea what you mean by "flow of my codes".

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a bug.

As documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql, the `ISNUMERIC` function returns 1 when the input expression can be converted to any of the following data types: `int`, `numeric`, `bigint`, `money`, `smallint`, `smallmoney`, `tinyint`, `float`, `decimal`, `real`.

Although the value '- 49.5' cannot be converted to `int`, `numeric` or `float`, it can be converted to `money`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(MONEY,'- 49.5')
```

returns `-49.50`

Answer (score 1):

Sql is defined like this and its mentioned in msdn

> ISNUMERIC returns 1 for some characters that are not numbers, such as plus (+), minus (-), and valid currency symbols such as the dollar sign ($).

Ref: [msdn ISNUMERIC()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql)

So `IsNumeric` gives you 1 because it encounters `-` and numbers( excluding space). But `convert` fails as the number has space inbetween.

IsNumeric can have funny behaviour.

Following also returns 1

```
SELECT isnumeric('- .');
```

Edited:

You have said you cannot use anything else then `ISNUMERIC` but considering `ISNUMERIC` not known behaviour (could be bug in sql server)

Found an Interesting reference [ISNumeric() StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76834/what-is-the-logic-behind-isnumeric-for-certain-special-characters) saying following;

> If you are using SQL Server 2012+, Use `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST` instead to check if a string can be convertible to some given type or not. Where they provide adequate functionality, these are preferable to `TRY_PARSE`, because the latter involves more expensive processing via CLR integration.

Comment: I think it's not true about my case! because my parameter is '- 49.5' and not '-'. So SQL server should check whole of parameter and not only one character

Comment: IsNumeric could have funny behaviour. Beware.

Comment: This non-documented behaviour of isnumeric could be bug in sql @SiamakFerdos

Answer (score 1):

Looks like '- 49.5' . (space between minus and number) is not a number. **Oracle** has the same problem:

```
select cast('- 49.5' as float) from dual
```

Gives the error: 
[Code: 1722, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-01722: invalid number

This works fine:

```
select cast('-49.5' as float) from dual;
```

Same with **JavaScript**:

```
Number("-49.5")
-49.5
Number("- 49.5")
NaN
```

And **Java**

```
System.out.println (Float.valueOf("- 49.5"))
```

Throws exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "- 49.5"

Same with **Python**

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 15 2017, 17:16:57)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> float("-49.5")
-49.5
>>> float("- 49.5")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: - 49.5
>>>
```

Same with **C** on Mac (Xcode)

```
printf("%f", atof("- 49.5"));
```

Prints: 0.000000